# hashed password of encrupted pdf

Tags: hash

I try to understand the meaning/name of individual strings which are separated by '*' in the following pdf hash.txt , but I can't get any description,,,Is there anybody to help please!? 
MyPDF.pdf:$pdf$4*4*128*1028*1*16*652fc762fdb12c47a5f90ddd2b99b809*32*dd86d858f914809078a4a47348d32c0fc4e9c08042a10e6434b48b698de7731f*32*3c1e693526d5bc8da15b99eea6cbc6ed2c2397e23e2c39d1974fdc004c588cff:::::MyPDF.pdf

Comment: hashed password of encrypted pdf

Comment: hash.txt description in pdf